# In Vue-CLI run dev, fail.

Tags: npm, vue.js, vue-cli

In the vue-cli, I want to `npm run dev`, but get the bellow error:

```
$ npm run dev

> vuejs-playlist@1.0.0 dev /Users/den/Desktop/Test/vue/vuejs-playlist
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot

sh: cross-env: command not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! vuejs-playlist@1.0.0 dev: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the vuejs-playlist@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/den/.npm/_logs/2018-02-02T11_54_11_067Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 2):

Try as follows for @vue/cli

```
npm run serve
```

Answer (score 1):

In your traceback:

> Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

You should in your project root directory install the dependencies:

```
npm install
```

Or use its logogram `npm i`

Answer (score 0):

As both answers before stated your build failed due needing to first:

```
npm install
```

Once that is complete, check your package.json file.

In there will have the default options for `npm run` followed by your build script option.

Example:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build"
  }
}
```

Resulting in your `npm run serve` is the same as `vue-cli-service serve`

Reference: [Vue Docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/cli-service.html)